# How to remove unused javascript in GatsbyJS?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, code-splitting, loadable-component

So, react-lazy & suspense does not work in gatsby as React.lazy and Suspense is not yet available for server-side rendering. But, we can use Loadable Components(https://loadable-components.com/docs/getting-started/) for that instead. So, I have used loadable components in gatsby & have also used & configured gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr in gatsby-config.js file. But, I am getting "WebpackError: Invariant Violation: loadable: SSR requires `@loadable/babel-plu  gin`, please install it." while deploying it on netlify. So, I am not able to split the js code. If anyone has tried it before or have similar things happened in past & have fixed it, then kindly help me out.

Comment: Have you tried to add the plugin to webpack, refer to this doc: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/

Comment: Try `npm install -D @loadable/babel-plugin` and then in your babel config add `@loadable/babel-plugin` to the plugins array.